# How can I copy data from one MongoDB collection to another using jenssegers

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, lumen, jenssegers-mongodb

I wanted to copy specific attributes from all documents in one MongoDB collection to another. I am using Lumen (v6.0.2) with jenssegers/mongodb(3.6.0). Is it possible to do it without looping through the documents?

Comment: what does ` all documents` mean here?

Comment: Suppose my source collection has 1 million document, with 20 attributes in each document. I want to copy all the 1 million documents, but 2 specific attributes only, to the target collection. Iterating in a loop might take sometime, since the actual number of documents in in many millions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out. Assuming that I wanted to copy 2 attributes, ID and updated_at from sourcecollection to targetcollection

```
DB::collection('sourcecollection')->raw(function($collection) {
 return $collection->aggregate(array(
 array(
 '$project' => array(
  'ID' => 1,
  'updated_at' => 1
 )),
 array(   
  '$out' => 'targetcollection'
 ),
 )   
 );
}
 );
```